# What is the NCV prefix?

Tags: datasheet

This sentence is seen on numerous datasheets:

*NCV Prefix for Automotive and Other Applications Requiring Site and Control Changes.*

The part numbers in those datasheets usually have this prefix as an alternative part number. For instance On Semiconductor's `MC33079` is also named `NCV33079`.

Is this some manufacturer-independent system for more easily matching part numbers?

All the search engine hits about this are just datasheets.

Comment: Did you copy that incorrectly? I found "NCV prefix is for automotive and other applications requiring site and change control." for the MC34063A.  Did you find any non-OnSemi datasheets?  My guess is that you can get more control over manufacturing of the part, if you need it in high volume and have special needs, e.g. safety.

Comment: Nope: https://www.google.com/search?q="NCV+Prefix+for+Automotive+and+Other+Applications+Requiring+Site+and+Control+Changes."

Answer (score 2):

Answer from ON Semiconductor tech support. The letters do not stand for anything. It is ON Semiconductor's code for designating parts which meet certain quality regulations in the automotive industry.  More specifically, on some data sheets it is stated in a footnote that NCV devices meet the AEC-Q100 quality standards.